# How to create a page break in WatchKit?

Tags: swift2, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'd like to put a group onto the storyboard and have it occupy the watches full screen regardless if 38mm or 42mm. This seems fine except when I want to add more items under it, then the top group can no longer be `Relative to Container` because it makes it too big.

Is there something like a page break or make the separator control work like a page break so that everything above it fits the screen, and everything below it is off the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can add screen size determinants to just about any UI object.  In the Attributes inspector, there are faint plus signs to the left of UI objects. Similar to the size classes for iOS, these let you set one for 38mm and one for 42mm, so you can use fixed size objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a top level vertical group that would contain two child groups. The first child group would have a height of "Relative to Container" and have all the UI that you want the user to initially see. The second child group could have a different height and all of the content you want to show up when a user scrolls below the initial screen.

Comment: That didn't work as expected. It made the first child group almost act as a `Sized to Fit` when selecting it as `Relative to Container`. So far, I've made the the first child group `Fixed size` to 170 for the 42mm, but that doesn't seem like it will last once new sizes are introduced and have to update all the screens that need that functionality :(